# wso2 emm 2.2.0 device udid url does not return anything

Tags: wso2

After successful profile installation, i am unable to get device info from agent-check.jag. It onl returns username{}. Instead it should ideally pass the deviceid, access token, refresh token and client credentials.

```
var deviceCheckURL = mdmProps["iOSAPIRoot"] + "devices/udid";
var challengeToken = session.get("iOSChallengeToken");
var payload = {"challengeToken" : challengeToken}; 
serviceInvokers.XMLHttp.post(deviceCheckURL, stringify(payload), function (restAPIResponse) {
    var status = restAPIResponse["status"];
    if (status == 200) {
        var responseContent = parse(restAPIResponse.responseText);
        response["status"] = 200;
        response["content"] = responseContent; # Here response is just username{}.
    } else {
        response["status"] = 200;
        response["content"] = {"deviceID" : null};
    }
});
```

Not sure why it is happening? Any issues related to roles?